# Geometric interpretation of Holder condition (flatness?)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose that a function $f$ satisfies the [Holder condition at a point](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/H%C3%B6lder_condition) $\overline{x}$.

**What is a geometric interpretation of this behavior?** Should the function be "flat" in some sense at that point?

Comment: No, by any means, since $\alpha\le 1$. Ideally, it should look like $\sqrt \lvert x\rvert$ does at $\overline x=0$.

Comment: $\alpha$-Hölder continuous functions “are not worse than” $x^\alpha$ near $0$.